# Dynamics 365 FakeXrm "usersettings" entity error

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, fakexrmeasy

I have this piece of code in my Dynamics 365 plugin,

```
 private int? RetrieveCurrentUsersSettings(IOrganizationService service)
    {
        var currentUserSettings = service.RetrieveMultiple(
            new QueryExpression("usersettings")
            {
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("timezonecode"),
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    Conditions =
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression("systemuserid", ConditionOperator.EqualUserId)
                    }
                }
            }).Entities[0].ToEntity<Entity>();

        return (int?)currentUserSettings.Attributes["timezonecode"];
    }
```

and I am writing a UnitTest for it with FakeXrm, and while debugging I am getting an error, in this query expression.

Here is my fake Xrm code.

```
  Entity systemUser = new Entity("systemuser");
        systemUser.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        Entity userSettings = new Entity("usersettings");
        userSettings.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        userSettings["timezonecode"] = 71;
        userSettings["systemuserid"] = systemUser.ToEntityReference();

        fakedContext.Initialize(new List<Entity>()
        {
            workOrder, owner, invoiceNote, userSettings
        });
```

The question is, how to create **usersettings** entity in FakeXrm and provide proper attributes to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am glad that you followed my suggestion to ask the question on StackOverflow.

Anyway you should have pointed out that you asked the same question on GitHub on the [FakeXrmEasy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy) repository and that the solution was provided there with this [answer](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/issues/358#issuecomment-438732037).

Long story short, the problem with your UnitTest was that you were missing  `fakedContext.CallerId = systemUser.ToEntityReference();` and that was needed because you were using `ConditionOperator.EqualUserId`in your query.

Best Regards, Betim Beja.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

```
           Entity systemUser = new Entity("systemuser");
            systemUser.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            fakedContext.CallerId = systemUser.ToEntityReference();
            IOrganizationService service = fakedContext.GetOrganizationService();
            Entity userSettings = new Entity("usersettings");
            userSettings.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            userSettings["timezonecode"] = 71;
            userSettings["systemuserid"] = systemUser.ToEntityReference();
```